How to disable options with especific value in all selects with same name?
I have several selects like this:
<select id="slctDat1" name="slctDat1" class="form-select">
      <option value="1">Text1</option>
</select>

<select id="slctDat2" name="slctDat2" class="form-select">
      <option value="1">Text1</option>
</select>

I know how to select them all with
$('select[name="slctDat[]"]')

What I need the program to do is to get the selected value of the select 'onchange' and disabled that value on all of them so it would look something like this:
<select id="slctDat1" name="slctDat1" class="form-select">
      <option value="1" selected disabled>Text1</option>
</select>

<select id="slctDat2" name="slctDat2" class="form-select">
      <option value="1" disabled>Text1</option>
</select>


I noticed that the SELECT on the snippet you provided have the same class. I imagine this is true for the rest.
With this in mind, you could have something like this:
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
     * Function to disable selected value 
     * in all selects with class 'form-select'
     */
    function disableSelectedValue() {
        /*
         * Get the selected value
         */
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        
        /*
         * Disable the option with the 
         * selected value in all selects 
         * with the same class
         */
        $('.form-select option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === selectedValue) {
                /*
                 * Disable the option
                 */
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                /*
                 * Ensure other options are enabled
                 */
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); 
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Attach the function to the change 
     * event of all selects with the class 
     * 'form-select'
     */
    $('.form-select').on('change', disableSelectedValue);
});

I imagine that this is what you had in mind.

Working good! this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!
